# Login to Google Spreadshet API using ClientLogin and PHP/cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the ClientLogin method and cURL to login to the google API's. This works fine and I receive a Token for further usage. I can now query docs.google.com by using

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
            "GData-Version: 3.0",
        );

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

This works fine and I get a list of all the documents available in my google docs account. But if I try the same query to spreadsheets.google.com with the URL obtained from the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list_of_spreadsheets):

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
```

I get a 401 error saying that the token used is invalid. I am using the same token and query in both cases. Do I need a different token for the google spreadsheets api?

Edit:
This is how I request the Token:

```
        $clientlogin_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
        $clientlogin_post = array(
            "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
            "Email" => "my email",
            "Passwd" => "my password",
            "service" => "writely",
            "source" => "my application name"
        );

        $curl = curl_init($clientlogin_url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientlogin_post);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
        $auth = $matches[1];
        curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: the same token should be fine, but comment out $curl = curl_init(); and use the same $curl object for spreadsheets.google.com as well. Let me know if that helped

Comment: unfortunately this has no effect

Comment: Ah, I think You need to auth for all domains. I think google treats docs.google.com and spreadsheets . google .com as two different services requiring auths of their own. You can quickly test ths out by -> 1. get list of google docs, save auth  2. use the same auth for spreadsheets, capture the failure, and 3. use the same auth for google docs again, if this works, then our assumtion is right.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you meant, but I queried google docs, queried spreadsheet and then queried docs again. I closed the curl connection after each query. Query 1+3 work fine, query 2 still has the same error

Comment: Ok, That means - The auth is actually valid and is tied to specific domain.  Thats why 1+3 work fine. this failed for 2 because, 2 is expecting a token for itself. By this test we have confirmed that 2 indeed is not failing due to an invalid auth!

Comment: I added the way I request the token. Just requesting a second token the same way and using it for the spreadsheet api doesn't work.

Comment: Ok updated ans... Peace!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - Yes. You need to generate different tokens for different services.  The service names you pass in to retrieve an auh token are different in each case. See here for more details - https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq

For example from the docs the req for spreadsheets would be

```
$clientlogin_post = array(
            "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
            "Email" => "my email",
            "Passwd" => "my password",
            "service" => "wise",
            "source" => "my application name"
        );
```